# Failed to install Production Provisioning Profile

Tags: macos, app-store

I created CSR, Mac App, Installer Certificates, and Production Provisioning Profile.

Certificates were installed correctly. However, Production Provisioning Profile could not be installed on my Mac. It told me

> Profile AppName(...)  could not be installed due to an unexpected
>   error."

I renewed everything again for nearly ten times. Still got failed.

*P.S. Development Provisioning Profile can be well installed.  My app cannot be submitted to AppStore for this reason. I have reported this problem to Apple. No reply yet.*

Does anybody know why?

Comment: I've been encountering the same issue - did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Now, the answer of your question had been answered by apple.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1759/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011373

Check it out

Comment: It's helpful. Production Provisioning Profiles is not necessary as my product doesn't iCloud and push notifications.